# Install Win 8.1 and VS 2013 on virtual machine for Win mobile development

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

On my laptop I have installed Win 7 and VS 2012.But I need to get ready for the Microsoft exam for the "windows store apps using HTML 5, css and javascript". So my idea is to install Win 8.1 and VS 2013 trial versions for get hands on practice for above exams.So my question is can I install Win 8.1 and VS 2013 trial versions on my Laptop without removing the current Win 7 and VS 2012 (Maybe a virtual machine or something like that)?If you know how to achieve above goal please let me know.

In short my whole idea is to get practice for developing Win 8 apps for mobile. If you have other suggestions without installing the above software, please let me know also.

Comment: Download VirtualBox, install Win 8.1 from iso.

Comment: Updating a Windows 7 system to Window 8 would actually be really simple. If you have the money. And if you're willing to then live with Windows 8. :)

Comment: @stakx That is the case.I don't like to live with Win 8 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone App Development requires Hyper-V & SLAT to run the emulator. That requires your host OS to be at least Windows 8 or better. On a virtual machine you will be able to develop apps, but you won't be able to run them on the emulator.

You can run Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 side by side, but then you would have to upgrade the host machine to Windows 8 Pro.

When both your laptop and your virtualization software support the required CPU features, it is also possible to run the emulator on top of Windows 7.

For more information [see this link on the Nokia Developer Portal](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator) (Thanks for adding that GSerg!)

Comment: If your CPU is good enough, and the virtualization software supports it, the emulator will work in the host OS.

Comment: Do you know any alternative for run emulator without installing it on my laptop?

Comment: @GSerg Did you mean will it(emulator) run on virtual machine also ?

Comment: @Sampath Yes, I meant that - e.g. see http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator. It's about VMWare, VirtualBox should be no different.

Comment: @GSerg Yep,Thanks.That link will help me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

General answer ([jessehouwing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19333884/240733) is more accurate):

If your notebook has enough main memory, CPU power, etc. and the CPU ideally supports certain virtualization features, then you should be able to install Windows 8 inside a virtual machine.

To give you an idea how simple this could be, here's an example:

- install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
- start it and set up a virtual machine with the proper CPU and OS settings
- define a virtual hard disk that's large enough (this will end up being a file inside your current OS, no need to repartition your real hard disk drive)
- get your Windows installation medium ready (a CD or ISO file will do)
- point your VM's virtual CD drive to that installation medium
- start the virtual machine and install Windows inside it